# "perhapsy" as a slang term for "perhaps"

Tags: slang

I've recently heard somebody answered "Yes, perhapsy."

Or could it be "perhapsee"?

Could this be used as a slang term for "perhaps"?

It happened in NYC area a few weeks ago.

Comment: I lived in NY for two years and never heard this expression.

Comment: @virmaior The person was a young black boy. Could it be ebonics?

Comment: What was the question he was replying to? I don't suppose it could have been a contraction of _"perhaps he..."_?

Comment: It's merely a case of "*y*-fying" *perhaps* (on the lines of *iffy*). Not slang really, not widely used, but will always be understood. "Is he coming the party?" "Yes, perhapsy." (Yes, but then again, maybe, kind of may come. There's a chance he may not, you know ...)

Comment: Reminds me of the British mannerism of adding *-ish* to arbitrary adjectives to denote vagueness. Like *soonish*. I think I even heard *peckish-ish* once.

Answer (score 4):

To directly answer, A quick googling (perhapsie, perhapsy, perhapsee) suggests that the word you heard is **not** widely used to mean "perhaps", although it might catch on at some point!

(Notably, Perhapsy is the name of a band which might be occluding results for that form)

Also, kind of tangentially, I don't think that this kind of usage is *really* "slang". In order to be slang, I think it would have to be further abstracted from the accepted normal word: see drug slang like "blow"="cocaine", "molly"="MDMA". It looks more like an ad-hoc construction from "perhaps", with the intention of seeming more casual or cute, perhapsie.

Also also, in response to your comment above, "ebonics" is not a widely accepted term for the variety of English spoken by, among other people, black urban youth. See [Wikipedia: African American Vernacular English](http://www.wikipedia.org/AAVE)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a contraction of *perhaps so*

> A: Did they know where she was?
>   B: Perhaps so --> Perhapsy
>
> A: Will he pass?
>   B: Perhaps so --> Perhapsy

A possible spelling variation might be: *perhapsi* rather than *perhapsee*. It also reminds me of *pepsi*. Words ending in double e are rare in English although not unheard of, *committee* being one that springs to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's most likely to be a personal or family idiom rather than slang. Some people like to play with language and come up with their own variants. For example, my own family calls milk "bookum bookum" (long story).

Yes, sometimes a term like that will catch on and become slang for a community (whether large or small). I'd say the "perhapsie" won't catch on fast, but you never know.

Answer (score 0):

I found the word *perhapsy* in title of e.e. cummings's poem "warped this perhapsy".

I have used *perhapsy* to name my music project based in Oakland, CA, although it originated in Ann Arbor, MI while I attended The University of Michigan School of Music.